# Which agricultural crops attract rodents?

Tags: mammals, agriculture, rodents

Are there any data on rodent populations per acre of different types of agricultural crops?

Comment: "Which agricultural crops attract rodents?" - I guess which they can eat :D corn, wheat, oat, etc... with high starch (and so energy) content. but almost everything I think.